# EAP 7.1 vs Elytron - SAMLv2

Tags: jboss7.x, saml-2.0, elytron

I am currently evaluating the moving of a legacy JBoss EAP 6.1 application from a Kerberos based security domain to SAMLv2 with JBOSS EAP 7.1 with Elytron (PicketBox is deprecated and not working properly).

Now I find it hard to find any proper example or documentation how this can be done in EAP7.1.

Is the idea to simply make use of Keycloak Adapters? I was not able to make it work.

Any help is appreciated.

Regars, Chris

Answer (score 0):

Elytron does not provide any solution for SAML. Yes, you should go with Keycloak Adapter way.

Comment: Just for clarification: When using Elytron, do I now need a Keycloak server in addition to the main WildFly/JBoss server in order to integrate authentication via SAMLv2, even if I actually want to connect another identity provider such as Microsoft ADFS? With Picketlink, all this was previously integrated in WildFly/JBoss.

Comment: Yes. Picketlink is deprecated now and will be removed in future from WF. Yes, Keycloak is the way now.